# Looking for equivalent workout to Upright Barbell Row excersie

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding, strength-training, barbell-rows

i'm looking for an equivalent workout to this shoulder workout i've been practicing.

I had to stop practicing this because my wrists hurt! (both my wrists were broken when i was a kid)

Any help is greatly appreciated !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since upright rows stress the traps and the shoulders, I would switch to using barbell or dumbbell shrugs.  Your shoulders won't get as much work, but, if done correctly, the traps should benefit.  Additionally, either exercise should reduce any strain on your wrists.